# How to group by set a null column with sum(column)?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
  NAME, 
  DESCRIPTION, 
  NULL "REMARKS", 
  SUM(PRICE) 
FROM PRODUCT 
GROUP BY NAME, DESCRIPTION, NULL;
```

then I get this error message "not a GROUP BY expression"

OR

```
SELECT 
    NAME, 
    DESCRIPTION, 
    NULL "REMARKS", 
    SUM(PRICE) 
FROM PRODUCT 
GROUP BY NAME, DESCRIPTION, REMARKS;
```

then I get these error message "REMARKS": invalid identifier and "%s: invalid identifier"

Can anyone correct me about this query?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, In your first query you do not need to add `NULL` into `group by` clause. You only need to add columns in `group by` which exists in your table.

```
SELECT 
  NAME, 
  DESCRIPTION, 
  NULL  as "REMARKS", 
  SUM(PRICE) 
FROM PRODUCT 
GROUP BY NAME, DESCRIPTION;
```

In your second query, error saying it could not find `Remarks` as `group by` always execute before `select`.

Comment: Hi, Zealous. I have followed your statement but not sure why I still get "not a GROUP BY expression"   SELECT 
  NAME, 
  DESCRIPTION, 
  NULL  as "REMARKS", 
  SUM(PRICE),  CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QTY) AS INT) "QTY"
FROM PRODUCT 
GROUP BY NAME, DESCRIPTION;

Comment: @S.Jenn It is saying `NULL` is not a group by expression. I have updated my answer. Let me know if you still do not understand.

Comment: This is my new statement and I still get "not a GROUP BY expression" cause by EQUIPMENT. SELECT NAME "n", DESCRIPTION "d", NULL as "REMARKS", SUM(PRICE) "p", EQUIPMENT "Eqp", CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QTY) AS INT) "qty" FROM PRODUCT GROUP BY NAME, DESCRIPTION;

Comment: here is the example fiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b651b13029be84c85022517dd4e5acfe

Comment: @S.Jenn Here is the another example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=726c72acc29833796978720a7e26a0ae

Comment: @S.Jenn First why are you doing `cast()` of row_number()? second you are missing `EQUIPMENT` in your `group by`. Please read how group by works and try to solve errors by yourself as that's the way to learn.